# box-sizing border-box does not work on max-width with padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got a bit of a problem understanding how this works.
Using box-sizing: border-box I assume the padding is included into the elements width. Hence when I set max-width: 0px, I ought to set the element width including padding to 0.

Now I have this case where I want to hide some contact info by setting max-width. However when I add a padding to the hidden span, the width of the element is 0 + padding.

Is this expected behaviour? Is that flex-box related? Is the overflow:hidden only applied to content despite the box-sizing?
I guess the issue itself is easily enough fixed by adding another node inside the action-slip but I am really curious why this occurs.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.action-icon-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.action-slip {
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  max-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.action-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: @white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action-icon-wrapper">
  <span class="action-slip green">contact</span>
  <span class="action-icon red">C</span>
</div>
```